# Excel isn't showing some of my Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel 365 isn't showing some of my Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels.

I set my axis label range for a stacked bar graph as =Sheet1!$A$2:$A$26 but it's only showing cells A2-A24.

I'm selecting Cells A2-A26

[image: screenshot]

The contents of cells A25 and A26 (Tasks 24 and 25) aren't showing up in Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels or on the graph.

Excel is only showing the contents of Cells A2-A24

[image: screenshot]

Tasks 24 and 25 aren't showing up on the graph

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how I can add more than 23 axis labels?

Comment: If you want help, I would recommend providing sample data and illustration of what isn't working.

Comment: @Isolated Thank you. I added some sample data and illustrations.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem. I would perhaps start over, create your chart with just a few rows and design it. Then expand to all your rows. If I had to guess, you selected only through row 24 for the data, but you're trying to label through row 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the problem by creating a chart through row 24, and then in a later step trying to label through row 26. You cannot label an item that's not charted.

I'm about 99% sure that's what happened to you. Start over and select all rows, then adjust your chart. Or, just create with a few rows, design your chart, then expand to all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, that mentioned above can be adding these values one by one. First, define the data for the horizontal and vertical axes and next add all of them one by one by selecting data range manually from your spreadsheet.
Considering your situation, when Excel adds the tasks 1-23 instead of 1-25 please take a look at what exactly happened with your data selection. Does your chart reflect your selection roughly? (Click "Edit" and check it) If tasks 24 and 25 are missing, they should be also not selected by the chart. If this is so, you can add them manually.